# What are the adverb for shabby and hardy?

Tags: phrases, verbs, meaning-in-context, adverbs, idiom-meaning

What are the adverbs for *shabby* and *hardy* are, and what are their corresponding noun and adjective?

Comment: They _are_ adjectives. If you look them up at the Free Dictionary, you will find that the answers are easily obtainable.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Shabby" and "hardy" are already adjectives; they provide a description of a noun.
2. "Shabby" and "hardy" do not have a corresponding noun; they are used *with* a noun. e.g. *A shabby person*.
3. The adverb for "shabby" is "shabbily", e.g. *He dresses shabbily.* There is no adverb for "hardy".

Comment: *[Shabbiness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/shabby#shabby__14)*? *[Hardiness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hardiness)*?

Comment: "Shabbiness" is actually a noun: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shabbiness?s=t